# Android Studio 3.2 - Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DeQk0wlFyM) from youtube to learn to make an android keyboard. I followed everything as described in it. I was able to build the project succesfully but whenever I try to run it I was getting the following error -

> Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk

So I googled for a solution and tried turning off Instant Run, then the above mentioned error was not appearing. The APK was installed to my device, but when I tried to enable the keyboard in the settings it was not found there. I tried it in device and 2 emulators, but problem is same everywhere.

I don't know what to do. I will copy my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tomsapp.keeskeyboard">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".KeesKeyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android:permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">

        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

and Build Gradle file here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tomsapp.keeskeyboard"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Please point out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @TheWanderer Which one - java files or xml files? If you have time you can just watch the video. Otherwise tell me how to send it to you via some message, mail or some other ways.

Comment: I'm sure you have already tried this, but what happens if you (1) Click File and then 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' or (2) Go To Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Instant Run --> uncheck 'Enable Instant Run to hot swap code / resource changes on deploy'? Do either of those solutions fix your problem?

Comment: @Silmarilos Yeah, I had tried those two solutions. None of those solved the issue.

Comment: downgrade version of compileSdkVersion. targetSdkVersion,  28.0.0-rc01 to replace 27.1.1 or 28.0.0 try. I hope it'll solve your problem.

Comment: @ViralPatel Since I am using latest gradle, the buildToolsVersion should be '28.0.3'. So when I downgraded compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion I am getting some errors while rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

In your build.Gradle file set minSDK to 22n so it matches your android vertual device.

Comment: The same issue exists still.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an image view in your app  then place that image Corresponding to image view in the *drawable* folder. Don't keep it in drawable -v24 folder and run on your device it may work